# Highlight some lines with google code-prettify

Tags: javascript, google-code-prettify

How can I highlight some lines with google code-prettify? Like on [Github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNtR5.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For highlighting 11th line use:

```
.prettyprint ol.linenums > li:nth-child(11) {
    /* css */
}
```